# Pass the Order ID in a shortcode used on WooCommerce Email Templates

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, shortcode

I cannot get the order ID in a custom woocommerce email template by shortcode. It does work directly.

Working code in `admin-new-order.php` template:

```
echo $order->get_id();
```

My shortcode below does not work and I don't know why. My goal is to eventually insert text variables like "Hello Firstname" by shortcode into the email template.

```
function custom_first_name($order, $order_id){
global $woocommerce, $post;
global $order_id, $order;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
return $order->get_id();
}
add_shortcode( 'custom-woocommerce-name' , 'custom_first_name' );
```

I add the shortcode to the in admin-new-order.php template via this code:

```
echo do_shortcode('[custom-woocommerce-name]');
```

`$order->get_id()` and the shortcode should both be outputting the order id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the **Order Id** from a shortcode used in `admin-new-order.php` template, you will have to use the following function code instead:

```
function wc_custom_first_name( $atts ){
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'wc-custom-name' ) );

    return $id; // return order id
}
add_shortcode( 'wc-custom-name' , 'wc_custom_first_name' );
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Then you will use the following in `admin-new-order.php` template file:

```
echo do_shortcode("[wc-custom-name id='{$order->get_id()}']");
```

Tested and works.

> #### Note:
>
> The **available arguments variables** passed to `admin-new-order.php` template are:
>
> - `$order`
> - `$email_heading`
> - `$additional_content`
> - `$sent_to_admin`
> - `$plain_text`
> - `$email`

Comment: One more question: Do you also know how I can use this shortcode in an ACF text field? I want to add that field into `admin-new-order.php` using `echo get_field( 'text_woocommerce_mail', 'option' );`. It now only works if I add it via `do_shortcode`.

Comment: @Bob Try to use `echo get_field( 'text_woocommerce_mail', $id );` or `the_field( 'text_woocommerce_mail', $id );` *(without echo)*